# Why can't I export Rock Band 1 songs to use in Rock Band 3?

Tags: rock-band-3, rock-band, version-differences, psn

I am trying to export Rock Band 1 songs for my PS3 so I can reuse most of the songs in Rock Band 3.

I read that the method to do this is installing the update for Rock Band to enable the option (works fine) and then buy the "Rock Band export key" from the PSN Store which I have done too.

However, when I select export from Rock Band, it gives me the warning message, and instead of exporting the songs, **it just shows the loading animation and nothing happens**.

Has anyone else suffered this problem? Does anyone know a solution for it?

I read it might be because the game and the key are from different zones. I realised I was using both Rock Band 1 and Rock Band 3 bought in the UK, but bought the export key in the Spanish PSN. Despite both should be PAL, I thought maybe one was PAL UK and the other one PAL EU, so I bought the export key again on the UK Store with another account. However, I got the same outcome.

Any ideas on what to do next? **How can I check what's the zone for each Rock Band?** (to make sure none of them are US imported to UK or something)

Comment: Hi, I just found out my RB1 disc is blus (blue ray third party US region1 retail) so despite being bought in UK it is from US.

I could use a friend's account to download the export key again (this time US) but once exported... will the songs work in my EU/UK Rock Band 3? Thanks!

Comment: Since this really isn't an answer to your actual problem (and just a general solution), I'll leave this as a comment. Try contacting EA live chat support and explain to them that you are having trouble exporting your Rock Band 1 songs on Rock Band 3, and they may generate a new code for you to use. I was having trouble with mine due to a different issue, and they immediately gave me a new code to use.

Comment: Codes are used when exporting from Rock Band 2. In Rock Band 1 what you need is to buy a DLC called "Rock Band Export Key" from the PSN Store.

Comment: Sorry, I was confusing Rock Band 2's export method with the first game. Typically though, you can check the zone of the game by the product's SKU on the side of the video game's box (BLUS = US).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this webpage http://www.rockband.com/support/export-rock-band, only certain songs can be copied from Rock Rand to a newer Rock Band. The reason this is the case usually has to do with licensing of music. Certain bands only license their music for some games, so they can't be ported to the next game.

Usually music licensing can be an issue with games. Region control can be even worse too for this. You could possibly check which zone your discs are by checking the game region. Look on the disc and check if it is NTSC or PAL and see if this makes a difference.